# ResearchKit Cancel button not working

Tags: ios, swift, cancel-button, researchkit

I am working on a project(Swift) using the ResearchKit and my Cancel bar button is not working.
I have found the following methods that should make it work

```
- (void)setCancelButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)cancelButtonItem {
    [super setCancelButtonItem:cancelButtonItem];
    [cancelButtonItem setTarget:self];
    [cancelButtonItem setAction:@selector(cancelButtonHandler:)];
}
- (void)cancelButtonHandler:(id)sender {
    STRONGTYPE(self.taskViewController.delegate) strongDelegate = self.taskViewController.delegate;
    if ([strongDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(taskViewController:didFinishWithReason:error:)]) {
        [strongDelegate taskViewController:self.taskViewController didFinishWithReason:ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReasonDiscarded error:nil];
    }
}
```

I get the Discard Results and Cancel popup, but nothing happens when I tap the Discard Results option.

Should I check for something else? Should I connect it somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking that button should call the `taskViewController(taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController, didFinishWithReason reason: ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason, error: NSError?)` method in your *task view controller delegate*. You have to manually dismiss the *task view controller* there.

See, for example, the implementation in `ORKCatalog`'s [`TaskListViewController.swift`](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/blob/master/samples/ORKCatalog/ORKCatalog/Tasks/TaskListViewController.swift#L121-L133):

```
func taskViewController(taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController, didFinishWithReason reason: ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason, error: NSError?) {
    /*
        The `reason` passed to this method indicates why the task view
        controller finished: Did the user cancel, save, or actually complete
        the task; or was there an error?

        The actual result of the task is on the `result` property of the task
        view controller.
    */
    taskResultFinishedCompletionHandler?(taskViewController.result)

    taskViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked out like that for me. I did something like this: func taskViewController(taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController, didFinishWithReason reason: ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason, error: NSError?) { switch reason { case .Completed: ... case .Saved, .Failed, .Discarded:
   taskViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
   break
  }